# Callbacks in Laika tests are not called

Tags: javascript, meteor, laika

[Meteor.collection.insert()](http://docs.meteor.com/#insert) accepts `callback` as an argument. As an example, one can create a brand new Meteor project and run the following code in the browser's console.

```
my_collection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
my_collection.insert(
    {some: "object"},
    function() {
        console.log("finished insertion");
    })
```

When I take this same code and put it in a Laika test, the `callback` argument never gets called. Here is my test code:

```
suite('testing Laika out', function() {
    test('inserting into collection', function(done, server, client) {
        client.eval(function() {
            my_collection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
            my_collection.insert(
                {some: "object"},
                function() {
                    console.log("finished insertion");
                    done();
                })
        })
    })
})
```

Anyone know why the callback function isn't called in this Laika test? This seems to be an issue for more than just `Meteor.collection.insert()`.

(I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, Meteor 0.7.0.1, Laika 0.3.1, PhantomJS 1.9.2-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call `done();` inside of your insert callback, when it doesn't exist in that function scope.  You actually need to listen for the insertion into `my_collection` and emit a signal which is picked up by either the client or server (the client in your case).  Also, you obviously won't be initializing your collection in your test; that should be done in your production code.

Try this instead:

```
var assert = require("assert");

suite('testing Laika out', function() {
    test('inserting into collection', function(done, server, client) {

        client.eval(function() {
            addedNew = function(newItem) {
                console.log("finished insertion");
                emit("done", newItem)
            };
            my_collection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
            my_collection.find().observe({
                added: addedNew
            });
            my_collection.insert(
                {some: "object"}
            )
        }).once("done", function(item) {
                assert.equal(item.some, "object");
                done();
            });
    });
})
```

Check out https://github.com/arunoda/hello-laika for the basic examples for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Mr. jonS90, if you were to run Laika with the **`--verbose`** flag, you would notice that an exception is quietly being thrown:

```
[client log] Exception in delivering result of invoking '/myCollection/insert': ReferenceError: Can't find variable: done
```

You see, you don't have access to `done()` in that context. Here's how you should revise your code:

```
test('inserting into collection', function(done, server, client) {
    client.eval(function() {
        my_collection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");

        finishedInsertion = function () {
            console.log("finished insertion");
            emit('done')
        }
        my_collection.insert(
            {some: "object"},
            finishedInsertion)
    })
    client.once('done', function() {
        done();
    })
})
```